# Selenium Webdriver _ issue related to 32bit/64bit server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created scripts on 64 bits server using selenium webdriver(eclipse).
but when i tried to run same script on 32 bits its not working.

Please let me know is their anything I need to do for it to work on both sides with no issues.

Comment: Share your code and the error.

Comment: I am not getting error message,. actually for 64bit i using laptop and for 32 bits i am using desktop on the both screen resolution is different,sorry i cant share the code wit you because its officeial site

Comment: @Ravinderkataria If you replace all instances of your site name with "example.com" and all private information (passwords, keys, page IDs, etc.) with dummy text, could you post some relevant snippets of it?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver will run on both 32 bit and 64 bit versions. Ensure that eclipse package is correctly chosen. For 32 bit windows chose 32 bit version of eclipse and for 64 bit windows chose 64 bit version of eclipse. Make sure that eclipse is configured correctly and then run the test.